# cipher.doFinal extra bytes

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes, pkcs#5

I am trying to encrypt an image in Android. I converted an image into a byte array. Later, I want to use the cipher text to create a brand new bitmap and save it. The code below is for my encryption

```
private static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
private static int KEY_LENGTH = 256;
...
public static byte[][] encrypt(byte[] plaintext, SecretKey key, byte[] salt) {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);

        byte[] iv = generateIv(cipher.getBlockSize());
        IvParameterSpec ivParams = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivParams);
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);

        return new byte[][]{salt, iv, cipherText};

    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

The problem is that cipherText has extra 16 bytes when the function returns.

For example, the plaintext is of size 7680000 bytes, but cipherText has 7680016 bytes. The image is 1600x1200, so 1600x1200x4= 7680000. I cannot save 7680016 bytes as an image :( What are these extra 16 bytes? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Where does it say that a cipher text has exactly the same number of bytes as the plaintext? And since when is a ciphertext an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not worry about the size of the file. When I have done similar task I had a 10 bytes extra in one particular bitmap image.

But, if you want to open the encrypted image to be openable, then you must alter the first **54 bytes** of the bitmap file with the original image. (the header 54 bytes of the bmp gives the bitmap information)
sample:[image]

I have encrypted this image file using openssl tool. Here how I selected first 54 bytes and replaced with the encrypted bitmap file.
[image]

If you wish to do something like this. Make sure that after decryption, you must also alter the 54 bytes from original header.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Are you saying I should just throw the "extra" bytes into a new line of pixels for the image? How would I later know how many extra bytes there were? Sorry if I misinterpreted it.

Comment: I recommend you just do not worry about extra bytes because it is the job of the "block chaining" sometimes you may get extra bytes, sometimes you will not. The only thing, the size of the file may be larger for a few bytes. If you wish, that the "ciphered" bitmap to be visible - just give the file correct header information. The "information" is only the first 54 bytes specially for bitmap images. The rest of the bytes gives you content information and should not be altered.

Comment: 54 bytes + ciphertext? Is this what I throw into a Bitmap?

Comment: I guess what confuses me the most is this: how do I pick width and height of the output image so that I include all ciphertext bytes (+54)?

Answer (score 2):

The extra 16 bytes are almost certainly due to padding.  Padding makes the encryption somewhat more secure, but if you don't mind getting rid of that, you can change the third component  of the cipher name ((which represents the padding algorithm) to `NoPadding`, to give a cipher name of `"AES/CBC/NoPadding"`.

You can find all the gory details about how cryptographic algorithm names work [in the Java security architecture docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Cipher).

In general, however, you shouldn't really rely on the size of the output generated by a cipher -- the ciphers are carefully designed to be as secure as possible, and you should leave the output size up to them.

Comment: Thank you for answer, really I see NoPadding helps to trim last block padding.

Comment: @BloodyHell666 If `NoPadding` is used, then you will need make sure yourself that the image size is a multiple of 16 bytes. If it is not, then you won't be able to encrypt it. AES is a block cipher which operates in conjunction with CBC mode only on plaintexts with length of a multiple of the block size (16 bytes for AES). Always use padding and don't make assumptions about the ciphertext size.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using padding. I simply add a new row of pixels and fill it appropriately. I coded it up. I can encrypt and decrypt a stored image.